# Why I get "Forbidden" status while I trying to redirect, with HAProxy, calls on CRC installed in a CentOS Docker container?

Tags: redirect, containers, openshift, haproxy

I have this scenario:

- a HOST machine running Debian that runs docker containers.
- a CentOS docker container that have **CodeReady Containers (CRC)** installed on itself. CRC working on the container, via command line, without problems.

I want access, from the Host machine, to CRC web console that works on `https://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing` (on a specific IP in the `hosts` file of the container).

---

I found this [RedHat guide for accessing CRC remotely](https://www.openshift.com/blog/accessing-codeready-containers-on-a-remote-server/).

And, applied to Docker containers, making the following **changes to `haproxy.conf`**:

```
global
log 127.0.0.1 local0
debug

defaults
log global
mode http
timeout connect 5000
timeout check 5000
timeout client 30000
timeout server 30000

frontend apps
bind CONTAINER_IP:80
bind CONTAINER_IP:443
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend apps

backend apps
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option ssl-hello-chk
server webserver1 CRC_IP:6443 check

frontend api
bind CONTAINER_IP:6443
option tcplog
mode tcp
default_backend api

backend api
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option ssl-hello-chk
server webserver1 CRC_IP:6443 check
```

**enabling forwarding** for the container:

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

and also [**starting CRC behind a proxy**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_codeready_containers/1.13/html/getting_started_guide/networking_gsg#starting-codeready-containers-behind-proxy_gsg):

```
$ crc config set http-proxy http://example.proxy.com:<port>
$ crc config set https-proxy http://example.proxy.com:<port>
$ crc config set no-proxy <comma-separated-no-proxy-entries>
```

I can successfully call the url `https://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing` from the Host machine (that have **dnsmasq as DNS resolver** properly configured)!!!

but I get this error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

**Notes:**

1. when CRC starts I have a warning: `WARN Wildcard DNS resolution for apps-crc.testing does not appear to be working`
2. even trying to login with `oc`, on Host machiche via command line, fail with an error message with status "Forbidden": `Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: unexpected response: 403`.

Where is the problem? I can't figure it out.

---

**For those interested, this is the [project's Git repository on GitHub.](https://github.com/kambei/centos-crc)**

Answer (score 1):

This message means that the user "system:anonymous" have not the permission to access the cluster. Have you done a login into the crc cluster as written in the documentation?

[3.3. Accessing the OpenShift cluster](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_codeready_containers/1.13/html/getting_started_guide/using-codeready-containers_gsg#accessing-the-openshift-cluster_gsg)

```
oc login -u developer https://api.crc.testing:6443
```

Comment: Of course I tried to login via command line too! But trying to login give me an error message with same status: Forbidden!

Comment: I received a suggestion regarding CORS. Is this the way? I would try something like [that](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/enabling-cors-in-haproxy/), but my HAProxy doesn't support lua-load. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final message when you run `crc start`

```
To access the cluster, first set up your environment by following 'crc oc-env' instructions.
Then you can access it by running 'oc login -u developer -p developer https://api.crc.testing:6443'.
To login as an admin, run 'oc login -u kubeadmin -p xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx https://api.crc.testing:6443'.
To access the cluster, first set up your environment by following 'crc oc-env' instructions.
```

Therefore, you have to run first to have the oc client available on the command line:

`crc oc-env`

Then you have to run login with oc client. In my installation was:

`oc login -u developer https://api.crc.testing:6443`